# Django, how to set a filter based on a queryset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have a queryset given by three different models:

```
class Sottocategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome del sottoprodotto', max_length=30)

class A(models.Model):
    codice_commessa=models.ForeignKey()
    prodotto=models.ForeignKey()
    sottocategoria=models.ForeignKey(Sottocategoria)

class B(models.Model):
    quantity=models.ForeignKey()
    price=models.DecimalField()
    sottocategoria=models.ForeignKey(Sottocategoria)
```

Now I have set the following for loop:

```
for sottocategoria_id, totale in 
 (B.objects.values_list('sottocategoria__id').annotate(totale=(Sum(F('quantity') * F('price')))):
....
```

I have the need to filter `sottocategoria__id` in the models B, that are present in the model A.

Ad example If I have in the `model A` sottocategoria equal to `{'abc','abcd','abcdf'}` and model B sottocategoria equal to `{'abc','abcd','abcdf', '1234'}`, in my for loop I want to filter only `{'abc','abcd','abcdf'}`.

Comment: What are `'abc'`, etc.? The names?

Comment: yep are the name of Sottocateoria models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
B.objects.filter(
    sottocategoria__name__in={'abc','abcd','abcdf'}
).values_list(
    'sottocategoria_id'
).annotate(
    totale=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
)
```

You also might want to `.order_by('sottocategoria_id')`, such that if you subscript, you subscript on a `sottocategoria_id`, not on the primary key of a `B` object:

```
B.objects.filter(
    sottocategoria__name__in={'abc','abcd','abcdf'}
).values_list(
    'sottocategoria_id'
).annotate(
    totale=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
).order_by('sottocategoria_id')
```

For example if you look for `sottocategoria`s that are referenced by an `A` you can use:

```
B.objects.filter(
    sottocategoria__in=Sottocategoria.objects.filter(a__isnull=False).distinct()
).values_list(
    'sottocategoria_id'
).annotate(
    totale=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
).order_by('sottocategoria_id')
```

for certain databases, like MySQL, it might be better to first materialize the ids:

```
sottocategoria_ids = list(Sottocategoria.objects.filter(a__isnull=False).values_list('pk', flat=True).distinct())

B.objects.filter(
    sottocategoria__in=sottocategoria_ids
).values_list(
    'sottocategoria_id'
).annotate(
    totale=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
).order_by('sottocategoria_id')
```

We can also query from the `A` model:

```
sottocategoria_ids = list(A.objects.values_list('sottocategoria_id', flat=True).distinct())

B.objects.filter(
    sottocategoria__in=sottocategoria_ids
).values_list(
    'sottocategoria_id'
).annotate(
    totale=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
).order_by('sottocategoria_id')
```

Comment: Okey thanks but the "name" variable changes and are not fixed. Are a field that client could fill to his liking

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco: then you obtain these, for example out of the `request.GET.getlist(...)` parameters. If you use a form (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) it might even be simpler. So the values in the `{'abc', ...}` does not need to be hardcoded, these can come from anywhere you want.

Comment: {'abc','abcd','abcdf'} are just an example, I don't know they values

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco: well if you make a form, or something else in HTML, then you can use this as a mechanism to provide values.

Comment: Okey in fact I want to extract them from the model A and filter model B based on them. I have a form that fill the db. After that I want to extract this value and used them to filter model B

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco: see edit, these will yield the elements that are referenced by an `A`.